# How to get content of html to show on content preview using window.print function?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am using window print function of JavaScript to show my HTML content. After clicking print button I can see the print dialog fine, but I can see the preview content. It just keep loading preview all the time.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="printArea">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover clientTable">
    <thead>
      <th>Client Code</th>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Card Number</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @forelse($listClient as $list)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ str_pad($list->id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) }}</td>
        <td>
          <img class="listPhoto" src="{{ asset('data/client/'.$list->photo)}}">
        </td>
        <td>{{$list->client_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->gender}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->card_number}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->job}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->phone1}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <a href="{{ url('client/detail/'.$list->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i> Detail</a>
          <span class="pad-rl-5"></span>
          <a href="{{url('client/edit/'.$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
          <span class="pad-rl-5"></span>
          @if($list->status ==0)
          <a href="{{url('client/enable/'.$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Active</a>
          @else
          <a href="{{url('client/disable/'.$list->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Inactive</a>
          @endif
        </td>
      </tr>
      @empty
      <tr>
        <td colspan=8>No record found.</td>
      </tr>
      @endforelse
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
function printContent(printArea) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById("printArea").innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

What I want is to preview content before I print the docs.

Any idea to solve this would be very appreciate.

Comment: It's seems you have forget to add click event handler.

Comment: Why don't you use `CSS` to control the presentation for printing? There is a  `media-type` for `print`. [Tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: @stanze I didn't forget to add click function. I just didn't show it here.

Comment: @sabithpocker As I describe above, I cannot see the preview content form my html content. How related with CSS?

Comment: are you able to fetch html content(innerHTML) firstly??..can you see those contents while debugging?

Comment: Surely, I can see the full content(innerHTML). And after I clicked the print button, if I want to see the preview Ctrl+Shift+P, I can show the preview content where I defined in my div.